# Read and Write Card Details using a Smart Card Reader

Tags: c#, smartcard

I need to integrate my application with a Smart Card Reader. Its a ContactLess Card Reader, Model No. ACR122U-A2 by Advanced Card Systems (www.acs.com.hk).

Currently my customer is already using another application developed by someone else, which uses this Card Reader. They usually place the Card on top of the Card Reader, even though its a ContactLess Card Reader.

This Card is used in a Club for member access. I need to read Member ID No. Name, etc. and also write the code to activate the Card.

I need sample C# code. I have gone through the technical manual on the manufacturer's site, but it provides too many low level details using Hexadecimal Codes. I am looking for a high level example using C#.

EDIT 1:
Since the data in the card is written by another application, whether I will be able to read the data meaningfully without knowing the schema details? I am sorry if this is a silly question, but I am programming the smart card for the 1st time.

Comment: You will need to know the protocol for communication between the card and the reader, we can't help you without a protocol.

Comment: About EDIT 1: no, you cannot read the data without knowing the details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an SDK for this product which indicates that ***it contains sample code in C#***.

http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122-SDK

I think this is the best place to start.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that SDK has to be purchased at USD 149. Is there no other way? The price seems high just to read a few card details.

Comment: They kind of have you in a position where you are left with limited  options -- I did notice that all of their SDKs have hardware packaged in, which is maybe why is costs so much.  Perhaps you can get the samples with out buying a full SDK?  I think that my clients would prefer to spend the $149 to find out what the samples contain, rather than have me spend a number of hours trying to do it from scratch, without vendor guidance.  Of course, there is no guarantee that the $149 would produce any value at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET) first. Note, that the reader needs typically less manufacturer-specific addressing than the card (at least if it supports PCSC). Cards tend to need slightly different low-level bytes, which is the reason, why you need the mentioned SDK manual for non-trivial accesses. I found a possibly helpful manual [here](http://www.scdeveloper.com/datasheet/REFACOS3V23.pdf).

To your Note 1: If the application was written without any security you may succeed to read the desired information. But if you then don't know, that member ID starts at offset a and is coded in b format c bytes long, you have to ask the information provider.