# Reading data from Smart Card Reader ACR122U-A2

Tags: c#-2.0, smartcard, smartcard-reader

This is a followup question to my earlier question: [Read and Write Card Details using a Smart Card Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016961/read-and-write-card-details-using-a-smart-card-reader)

I have got the SDK and gone through the reference manual and sample code. But the SDK mentions very low level details like turning light on or off, sending APDU commands, etc.

My requirement is to read the card data like member name, membership no., etc. which is stored inside the card.

My client has arranged the SDK from the vendor, but I am still no better at reading the data inside the card. Can anyone suggest what should I do next?

Also, how to find out the type of the card, i.e. whether its a MiFare card, or other PICC Card? There is nothing on the card to suggest this way or that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the SDK concerns the reader. However, you **need substantial additional information** concerning the card itself. Nobody here can help without that information. Still then the provider of the card has to provide documentation, where the data you want to read is stored, and which access rights are necessary to do so, which keys to use etc. It is very optimistic to expect, that everything to be known can be found out by looking at the card. Sorry, but your question is currently an invitation to guess based on no facts.